# convert line from text file into variables JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, text

I'm trying to extract the numbers individual lines from a text file and perform an operation on them and print them to a new text file.

my text file reads somethings like

10 2 5 2

10 2 5 3

etc...

Id like to do some serious math so Id like to be able to call upon each number from the line I'm working with and put it into a calculation.

It seems like an array would be the best thing to use for this, but to get the numbers into an array do I have to use a string tokenizer?

Comment: `java.util.StringTokenizer` has been replaced with `String.split(String)`. It's easier to use and makes your code a whole lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("mynums.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] numstrs = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // split by white space
    int[] nums = new int[numstrs.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[i]);

    // now you can manipulate the numbers in nums[]

}
```

Obviously you don't have to use an `int[] nums`. You can instead do

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[0]);
int m = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[1]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[2]);
int y = m*x + b; // or something? :-)
```

Alternatively, if you know the structure ahead of time to be all ints, you could do something like this:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("mynums.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
    ints.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

It creates Integer objects which is less desirable, but isn't significantly expensive these days. You can always convert it to an `int[]` after you slurp them in.

Comment: `int y = m*x + b;` sounds like some serious math to me just like the OP wanted :)